# sed not replacing lines

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I have a file with 1 line of text, called `output`. I have write access to the file. I can change it from an editor with no problems.

```
$ cat output
1
$ ls -l o*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jbk jbk 2 Jan 27 18:44 output
```

What I want to do is replace the first (and only) line in this file with a new value, either a 1 or a 0. It seems to me that sed should be perfect for this:

```
$ sed '1 c\ 0' output
 0
$ cat output
1
```

But it never changes the file. I've tried it spread over 2 lines at the backslash, and with double quotes, but I cannot get it to put a 0 (or anything else) in the first line.

Comment: You need `in-place` editing. See the man page for the `-i` flag.

Comment: …Or you could use [`ed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html), which I'm going to keep mentioning because I'm persistent and this is actually the kind of thing `ed` is for. (As opposed to adding a nonstandard extension to a stream editor so it can write back to files.)

Comment: sed operates on a stream and prints its output to standard out.  If you  want to modify your input file, take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sed operates on streams and prints its output to standard out.

It does not modify the input file.

It's typically used like this when you want to capture its output in a file:

```
#
# replace every occurrence of foo with bar in input-file
#
sed 's/foo/bar/g' input-file > output-file
```

The above command invokes `sed` on `input-file` and *redirects* the output to a new file named `output-file`.

Depending on your platform, you might be able to use sed's `-i` option to modify files in place:

```
sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/g' input-file
```

NOTE:

Not all versions of sed support `-i`.

Also, different versions of sed implement `-i` differently.

On some platforms you **MUST** specify a backup extension (on others you don't have to).

Comment: +1 for speaking truth to power. There's a missing quote, though. Also, this answer could be improved by mentioning [`ed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) and the non-standard, but all-too-common `-i` flag.

Comment: GNU `sed` supports the `-i` option; most other versions of `sed` do not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler BSD also has that flag, but it requires the extension.

Comment: I looked for how to use `ed` for this, but could not find any examples of how to do an unconditional replacement. Whereas, `sed` is all over the place.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is an incredibly simple file, sed may actually be overkill. It sounds like you want the file to have exactly one character: a '0' or a '1'.

It may make better sense in this case to just overwrite the file rather than to edit it, e.g.:

```
echo "1" > output
```

or

```
echo "0" > output
```